# How to use satyan's Sugar ORM with @Table annotation

Tags: android, gson, sugarorm

Im very statisfied with SugarOrm for Android, but I ran into an issue. I'm using it with GSON for Json serializations and I want to get rid of `SugarRecord`'s id attribute. I know I should use `@Table` annotation and later exclude specific field from serialization using `@Expose`, but after annotating class with @Table I cannot use `.save()`, `delete()`,... methods on the object, as it is the case extending `SugarRecord`. I don't know how to persist objects using `@Table` annotation.

I found the [documentation here](https://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html) very limited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The document hasn't been updated for the annotation based persistence yet. The methods save(), delete() will be available as static methods on SugarRecord class.

So instead of doing this:

```
object.save()
```

You'd be doing this:

```
SugarRecord.save(object)
```

Check out some tests here to understand better.
https://github.com/satyan/sugar/tree/master/example/src/test/java/com/example/sugartest